# order by length of a column which is groub by

Tags: mysql

I have a query in mysql5.7.x like

```
select  CONCAT(YEAR(now()), '/', MONTH(now())) as yearmonth,
     a.country
    sum(sales)
from table1 as a
group by CONCAT(YEAR(now()), '/', MONTH(now())) as yearmonth,  a.country
order by length(CONCAT(YEAR(now()), '/', MONTH(now())))
```

In this query order by length(group column) is not allowing.

the data should look like

```
2018/12
2018/11
2018/10
2018/09.......etc
```

can anyone pls help me how to sort like this. Thank you

Comment: `CONCAT(YEAR(now()), '/', MONTH(now()))` is a constant, why are you grouping on it?

Comment: thank you ....I am facing the issue like 2018/12 is coming after 2018/9,2018/8,2018/7.... even I kept order by CONCAT(YEAR(your_date_column), '/', MONTH(your_date_column)) desc

Comment: See revised answer

Answer (score 2):

`Group by` cannot have Column Alias. Also there is no point of using `NOW()`. I guess your table has **Date** Column.

Besides, Length is not needed here because Length of `2018/12` is character length of specified date which is `7`

```
select  CONCAT(YEAR(your_date_column), '/', MONTH(your_date_column)) as yearmonth,
     a.country
    sum(sales)
from table1 as a
group by CONCAT(YEAR(your_date_column), '/', MONTH(your_date_column)),  a.country
order by CONCAT(YEAR(your_date_column), '/', MONTH(your_date_column))
```

Comment: That's a good catch on the `now()` and also the nonsense `Length()` in the `ORDER BY`

Comment: I am facing the issue like 2018/12 is coming after 2018/9,2018/8,2018/7....
even I kept order by CONCAT(YEAR(your_date_column), '/', MONTH(your_date_column)) desc

Comment: You cannot order by like this. You need to zero-pad the month otherwise `2000/2` appears after `2000/10` sorted ascending.

Comment: Or keep it as number like 201812 201801. When you sort chars 12 had precedence over 1 which is not the case for numbers

Comment: Here is my query
SELECT
  CONCAT(YEAR(a.dattimin), '/', MONTH(a.dattimin)) AS 'dates',
  COUNT(DISTINCT (a.sysno)) AS 'Counts'
FROM table1 a  
where date (a.dattimin) BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2018-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d') AND STR_TO_DATE('2018-12-12', '%Y-%m-%d')
GROUP BY CONCAT(YEAR(a.dattimin), '/', MONTH(a.dattimin))
ORDER BY CASE WHEN LENGTH(CONCAT(YEAR(a.dattimin), '/', MONTH(a.dattimin)))=6 
  THEN  CONCAT(YEAR(a.dattimin), '/0', MONTH(a.dattimin))
              WHEN LENGTH(CONCAT(YEAR(a.dattimin), '/', MONTH(a.dattimin)))=7 
  THEN  CONCAT(YEAR(a.dattimin), '/', MONTH(a.dattimin)) END;